# Laravel GraphQL Vs REST API Performance

Tags: laravel, rest, graphql, lighthouse, laravel-lighthouse

I am using the below package for the graphql integration in laravel.I think the package is slow. While comparing the Graphql Vs REST API in local environment, REST API is very fast compared to the graphql package,but in all the documents I can able to see that grapql is faster than rest API can you comment for the reason guys?

composer require nuwave/lighthouse

REST API - 61 ms with the size of 787.03kb
GraphQL  - 744 ms with the size of 806.5kb

Kindly help me, If I am making any mistakes. Please refer the screenshots.

[image: REST Postman request]

[image: GraphQL Postman request]

Comment: Do not share code as images, the images will eventually go down, the code can by copy-pasted (it is even easier than putting an image...)

Comment: There is a whole section on performance: https://lighthouse-php.com/6/performance/schema-caching.html#deployment. Out of the box Lighthouse is slower, but it's not comparing the same thing. You get a lot extra's and that takes some extra time, not as much as in your unoptimized example but with an example as simple as yours I doubt it will ever be faster when purely looking at server response times.

Comment: @Alex I think its not server response based because I am using local environment.

Comment: Locally you also run a (development) server. So the times (61ms and 744ms) are your local server response times. That is what we call the time your app takes to respond. Please look at the documentation provided.

Comment: okay I will refer the documentation @Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you directly compare the time it takes to return some fixed data, Lighthouse will always be slower then doing the same through an endpoint that just returns JSON.

A GraphQL server simply does more work, for example:

- parse and validate the query
- ensure the query matches what the schema offers
- resolve the data dynamically, allowing each field to control how it is returned
- ensure the returned data adheres to what the schema promises

The strengths of GraphQL become apparent when your queries (or mutations) become larger and more complex. Validation will make sure everything works as intended, and loading of nested relations will allow you to save on round-trips.

Comment: Thanks spawnia for the comment. As you told  I am just checking with the fixed data, there is no nested relationships or any other complex queries. I will check and update with you guys.